# Examples of difficult Hamiltonian Cycle Problems

Tags: hamiltonian-path, data-sets, hamiltonian-circuit

I am working on implementing algorithms to solve Hamiltonian Cycle Problem. I need difficult problem graphs to test my implementations but my google-fu is weak and am unable to find any.

Please advise where I might find a set of difficult graphs for the Hamiltonian Cycle, or how to generate such graphs for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) contains some instances of Hamiltonian Cycle. Haythorpe [1] proposes [a set of around a thousand instances](https://sites.flinders.edu.au/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/fhcp-challenge-set/) which are claimed to be "structurally difficult" (not necessarily large).

---

[Haythorpe, Michael. "FHCP Challenge Set: The first set of structurally difficult instances of the Hamiltonian cycle problem." arXiv preprint arXiv:1902.10352 (2019).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.10352.pdf)